# OSGi Netbeans Development

Tags: netbeans, osgi, netbeans-7.2

I'm starting a project with OSGi, but I don't know how to do it. I use Netbeans 7.2. My doubt is what is better NetBeans or Eclipse? Someone have a good tutorial? In NetBeans I created a project, build a Activator class, but when I Run, it starts another NetBeans, I don't want to star another netbeans, I want a clean OSGi platform. Someone help me please! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a similar problem. I can create a single Maven OSGi bundle project and run it (it uses Felix), but I have no clue how to run a multi-bundle project.

Comment: Try using Bndtools with Eclipse! Much better!

Comment: I've worked on a large team project using bndtools with Eclipse and it was a nightmare, even worse when we tried to mavenize it. These days, NetBeans + Maven + OSGi are an excellent combination that just works right out of the box and, as a bonus, is CI friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at bndtools: http://bndtools.org/

It is only available as an Eclipse plugin, but IMHO it gives a much better OSGi development experience than PDE.

Answer (score 1):

Two good step-by-step tutorials:

- [NetBeans Platform 7.2 Quick Start](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html)
- [NetBeans IDE 7.2 Plugin Quick
  Start](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html)
- [NetBeans Platform Quick Start Using OSGi](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-osgi-quickstart.html)

As well as the [NetBeans Platform Learning Trail](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/all-docs.html)

Compare / Difference between [**Netbeans <--> Eclipse**](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/compare.html)

> but when I Run, it starts another NetBeans

You run your *Netbeans IDE* (for development) and there you start your *Netbeans Platform* Application.

Comment: But I don't want to create a module for NetBeans, I wanto to develop a free OSGi Bundle. Why Do I need to start NetBeans? Is there a way to don't start up?

Answer (score 1):

The OSGi support in Eclipse is more mature than that in NetBeans; you'll have to work out where the balance for you is in the trade-offs between your familiar development platform (I assume) and the greater level of OSGi support. (Eclipse's OSGi development support is a bit hidden, since it's all in the Plug-in Development Environment, or PDE.)